# Get table rows count from schema in MySql

Tags: mysql

I got the solution how to get the total rows table wise by below query

```
SELECT table_name "Table Name", SUM(TABLE_ROWS) "Total Rows"
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = {schema_name} AND table_name IN ('table_1', 'table_2', 'table_3')
GROUP BY table_name;
```

It will display all the rows till day.

But I want number of rows till last day. I am not getting any solution for this.

Is it possible by above query? Please suggest what is the way to get it the result.

Comment: do you want those 3 tables ('table_1', 'table_2', 'table_3') only?

Comment: Yes. It might be more than that but right now I need only for those 3

Comment: If you need particular table only then you are using information_schema. You can directly refer those tables and use union, aggregation feature correct?

Comment: @Gaj Not understand. Can you please give some example what is the best way to achieve the above requirement

Comment: Not directly. Why not run the query daily and push the result into a summary table.

Comment: Yes. I can do that. For each table need to write query but that might be not a good idea if I have 10 tables. For 1 and 2 is fine but if table more than that

Comment: I mean you can write like select 'table_1' as tbl_name, count(1) from table_1 where dt < current_date union all select 'table_2' as tbl_name, count(1) from table_2 where dt < current_date union all select 'table_3' as tbl_name, count(1) from table_3 where dt < current_date

Comment: If you have more tables then create one temp table and store all the required table names in that. Write stored function to find number of rows in each tables

Comment: @Gaj Good Idea. Thanx for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
SELECT table_name as "Table Name", count(*) as "Total Rows"
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = {schema_name} AND table_name IN ('table_1', 'table_2', 'table_3')
GROUP BY table_name;
```

Comment: Its look like a same query which I posted in my question.

Comment: @Shiladittya Chakraborty not quite and will only ever return 1 in the count

Comment: I have changed SUM(TABLE_ROWS) to count(*) for getting number of rows